# Selecting cousin element with XPATH

Tags: xpath

Given following markup

```
<div>
    <a>Username1</a>
</div>
<div>
    <button>Unblock</button>
</div>
<div>
    <a>Username2</a>
</div>
<div>
    <button>Unblock</button>
</div>
<div>
    <a>Username3</a>
</div>
<div>
    <button>Unblock</button>
</div>
```

How do I select button element which is a cousin of `a` element with text Username2?

I can select the `a` element with `//a[contains(., 'Username2')]`, so I thought that `//a[contains(., 'Username2')]/following-sibling::/div/button` would select the correct button, but that does not work. I think that it's not even valid XPATH.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were close:

```
//a[contains(., 'Username2')]/../following-sibling::div[1]/button
```

To navigate to the cousin you first have to go to the parent (`..`) and then to its sibling.

Note that the `following-sibling::` axis selects *all* following siblings, not only the first one. This means you must use `[1]` if you just want the first.

This would also work:

```
//a[. = 'Username2']/../following-sibling::div[1]/button
```

So would this:

```
//div[a = 'Username2']/following-sibling::div[1]/button
```